# Cleaning up code in recorded Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I used the Record Macro function to create this, but it runs real slow and I want to see if anyone had any ideas on how to **clean it up**.  It looks as if I have two sorts here doing the same thing?  Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Activations()
'
' Master_Button2_2_Click Macro
'

'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Index").Select
Columns("A:C").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B12000" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:C12000")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Sheets("Duplicates").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$L$4:$N$3476").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "Activate"
Sheets("Master").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$BU$11965").AutoFilter Field:=73, Criteria1:= _
    "A"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fairly straightforward although it isn't entirely clear what it is trying to accomplish. Here is a quick rewrite putting several [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to use to narrow down the affected work areas.

```
Sub Activations()
    ' Master_Button2_2_Click Macro
    Dim lr As Long

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    With Worksheets("Index")
        lr = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        With .Range("A1:C" & lr)
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With

    With Worksheets("Duplicates")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lr = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        With .Range("L4:N" & lr)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="activate"
        End With
    End With

    With Worksheets("Master")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lr = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        With .Range("A2:BU" & lr)
            .AutoFilter Field:=73, Criteria1:="A"
        End With
        .Select
    End With

    appTGGL
End Sub

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
End Sub
```

Sample data and a short narrative of explanation would have helped this question. We don't all speak english but we all speak code and data.